# Getting Typescript error when not passing in Props to a component already provided by a HOC wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I Have a Parent Component which passes in 3 props to a child component:

```
Class Invite extends Component {
    ...//

    render() {
        return 
          <div>
            <SignUpForm
              data={data}
              refetch={refetch}
              submitForm={this.handleSubmit}
            />
          <div>
    }
```

My child component has in addition a HOC wrapper around it :

```
export interface SignUpFormProps extends FormComponentProps {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  password: string
}

interface DataProps {
  refetch: any,
  data: Data,
  submitForm: any

}




class DesignerSignUpForm extends Component<SignUpFormProps & DataProps> {

    render() {
        return (...////);
    }

export default Form.create<SignUpFormProps>({ name: 'sign_up' })(SignUpForm);
```

I am facing an instric Attributes error as such:

```
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<SignUpFormProps, "email" | "firstName" | "lastName" | "password" | "wrappedComponentRef">, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)
```

Which I'm assuming is because the it expects the parent component to pass in all props that the child component expects from the interface definitions.

But I am struggling because the HOC wrapped around the child component will already inject these props. How do I let the parent component know to safely ignore the requirement that the props provided by the HOC don't need to be passed ?

Comment: `refetch={() => refetch()}` is sounds error prone. 1- is refetch() a prop? 2- make sure it is passed down. 3- missing this. if in same file.

Comment: Hi did you find an answer to this. I basically same problem for injected prop visibility. For now I am making my prop optional in interface but is there any other solution to the design of the HOC so it can hide the injected props from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

The parent component would still have to pass the props required but they can be null or undefined. 
If not, you can make them optional in your interface.